# iText7 - Set pdflayer color to black

Tags: colors, layer, itext7

I am working in a company that has a Engineering section. As one of the draftsmen I am asked if it's possible to edit the drawing pdf file so that only revision clouds have color red. All other items on the pdf should be black.

A exported pdf contains layers. The revision clouds have their own layer.

Is it possible to loop the layers and make them black?

I already checked the API but, can't find a direct answer here.
https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_layer_1_1_pdf_layer.html

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I already have some experience in iText7 for processing pdfannotations, but I am failing to see the logic here.

Comment: "Layers" in PDF actually is a misnomer; the PDF specification more clearly talks about "optional content groups" (OCGs). The practical difference is that each piece of content may be separately marked as belonging to a given OCG or not; even worse, a piece of content can be declared to belong to a union or intersection or a complement of OCGs. Thus, *making a layer black* actually means iterating all related contents, keeping track of the current color, and each time there is a switch of OCGs to switch to black or back to the color kept track of. More complex in the *even worse* situations...

Comment: To cut a long story short, iText does not offer high-level methods to access the content of a single layer (which sometimes even cannot be decided, see the "even worse" above). You can of course use low level methods to iterate all contents but that is not trivial.